# How to find hyphenated Strings

Tags: javascript

I search for specific words in a text and find them too. However, if the word I am looking for is divided into two lines by a hyphenation, the word will not be found. Here is a sample code.

```
searchString = "Hollywood";
newString = "";
text =  "In India Hollywood is called Bollywood.";

var i = 0;

i = text.indexOf(searchString, i);

newString += text.substring(0, i) +  " <<here begins my searchString>> " + text.substr(i, searchString.length) + " <<here ends my searchString>> " +
              text.substring(i + searchString.length);

console.log(newString);
```

If the searchString Hollywood looks like

```
Holly-<br>wood
```

it will not be found. 
How can I solve this problem in my Javascript code?

Comment: Since you can't guarantee where the hyphen will be, a quick and dirty solution is simply remove all of the hyphens from the target string as well as HTML.

Comment: Are you parsing HTML that actually has `<br>`, or plain text with newlines?

Comment: Remove `-<br>` from the string, then run the search? This will only work for `-<br>`, but if that's your only problem string it'll certainly solve it.

Comment: @JordanRunning I am parsing HTML with <br>

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do it, but one of them would be to get rid of the -
 altogether if they're present:

```
searchString = "Hollywood";
newString = "";
text =  "In India Holly-<br>wood is called Bollywood.";

filteredText = text.replace(/-<br>/,'');
var i = 0;

i = filteredText.indexOf(searchString, i);

newString += filteredText.substring(0, i) +  " <<here begins my searchString>> " + filteredText.substr(i, searchString.length) + " <<here ends my searchString>> " +
filteredText.substring(i + searchString.length);

console.log(newString);
```

In this case, we just replace the `-<br>` characters with an empty string. It might not be the best approach, but refining it would depend on the context in which you intend to use it.

I hope that the regex and replace idea can help you customize a solution that best fit your needs.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I don't want replace the "-<br>" Tag. Actually I want to find also those words, which are divided into two lines. The comment <<here begins my searchString>> would be in the first line and the comment <<here ends my searchString>> would be in the second line. I hope I'm explaining understandable.

Comment: I feel I do understand what you want, but the only way I would know how to do it would become quite tricky. You'd have, for a given word, to try to match the exact word and every iteration of that word with a -<br> inside of it, at all possible locations. It wouldn't be a one-liner anymore, but a function in itself. Maybe someone else might know of a way to make it as a one-liner. Basically, what I'm talking about is that for each search string, you'd be building multiples possible matching patterns and would evaluate each one of them.